# Flashvars won't load

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flashvars

I've got a weird problem with loading Flashvars into my flash application. I tried to isolate the code and try it in an other document, but the object returned is still empty.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="Div1">
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="630" height="671" id="testApp" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="{$this->siteUrl}/flash/testVars.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="one=1&two=2" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{$this->siteUrl}/flash/testVars.swf" width="630" height="671">
        <param name="movie" value="{$this->siteUrl}/flash/testVars.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="play" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="true" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="one=1&two=2" />
        <param name="wmode" value="window" />
        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
        <param name="menu" value="true" />
        <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
        <param name="salign" value="" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

This is my as3 code:

```
ExternalInterface.call('console.log', "Begin")
var obj:Object = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
for(var i:String in obj)
{
    this[i] = obj[i];
    ExternalInterface.call('console.log', "Parsing: " + i + " - " + obj[i])
}
```

It show begin nicely in the console window of Chrome, but it does not print the flashvars. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `this.root.loaderInfo.parameters`

Comment: Still comming up as undefined unfortunately..

Comment: Ah, forgot to say. Tested it with firefox, chrome and IE. All say undefined. I am sure this is the code, there is nothing else in the html document besides this and the body, head, html tags. I know the second call to EI works because the browser display's undefined in the console window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is a *'bug'* in Flash with the TLF Text component.
Including a TLF Text element within your document also includes the Text Layout Framework Runtime Shared Library (TLF RSL). The RSL prepends a preloader before your main movie

This means that your swf is no longer the first movie loaded and so it renders the FlashVars unaccesable.

Adrian Parr has an exelent blog item about this:
http://www.adrianparr.com/?p=137

Answer (score 1):

One work around is to embed the whole TLF runtime instead of loading it externally. The steps for doing so are described in [this how-to by adobe](http://adobe.ly/XkdeGY):

> To compile the TLF ActionScript assets in published SWF files:
>
> - Choose File > Publish Settings.
> - Click the Flash Tab.
> - Click the Settings button next to the Script menu.
> - Click the Library Path tab.
> - Select Merged Into Code from the Default Linkage menu.

This, obviously, increases your swf file size significantly.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try running this in Debug mode. The statement

```
this[i] = obj[i];
```

is giving exception. You can't do this in Actionscript unless your class is Dynamic. Commented the line and it worked.